# Java JComboBox Incompatible Types: Cannot be converted to string

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have this error when i try to add items in the JComboBox

> incompatible types: ComboBox cannot be converted to String

This is my method to load the data from database to the JComboBox...

```
public final void loadProducts()
{
    try 
    {
        String sql = "SELECT * from product";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            combobox.addItem(new ComboBox(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(1)));
        }
        combobox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

And this is the class

```
public class ComboBox
{
    private String key;
    private String value;

public ComboBox(String key, String value)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return key;
}

public String getKey()
{
    return key;
}

public String getValue()
{
    return value;
}
}
```

I have no idea what's causing it! Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `combobox.addItem(new ComboBox(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(1)));` makes no sense adding a jcombobox to a jcombobox

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this combobox.addItem(new ComboBox("Visible String 1", "Value 1")); -- combobox is the name of my JComboBox and the ComboBox is a class

Comment: addItem only takes strings, hence the error. Why don't you re-implement your toString() properly and use that instead.

Comment: try add in class `ComboBox` empty constructor and method setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to be certain without knowing how `combobox` is declared and at which line the Exception is being thrown...

My guess: `combobox` is declared as a JComboBox that takes a `String` and you the Exception is being thrown since a `ComboBox` is being added instead of a `String`.

Possible correction: declare the JComboBox to hold instances of `ComboBox`:

```
private JComboBox<ComboBox> combobox;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the Type Parameter in Code Properties to `ComboBox` or whatever your class name that will be put inside `.addItem` method

[image]